# rewrite Linq 'to other format'

Tags: c#, linq

Yep, this is a weird title, i know, maybe the text below helps:

normally we write our linq like this (call this 'format b'):

```
persons.where(z=> z.year > 200);
```

now i have written a linq statement in 'format a'

```
act = from n in act
where ! (n.Ready && n.ReadyDateTime !=null && (DateTime.Now - n.ReadyDateTime.Value).Days > 30)
select n;
```

In format 'b', i couldn't use the ! operator, so i ended up with format 'a'

It works allright, but i am curious how i can write it in 'format b'

En i'm also curious how i call 'format a' and 'format b' :)

Comment: b) Fluent lambda syntax. a) Query comprehension syntax

Comment: “In format 'b', i couldn't use the ! operator” – why not? It works completely fine.

Comment: @Konrad, i had this: .where(!(...)) and it gave me a compile error

Comment: Well the negation should go inside the lambda, as shown in SLaks’ answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "format b" is called Method Calls.

To convert your *query comprehension syntax* to method calls, write

```
act.Where(n => !(n.Ready && n.ReadyDateTime != null
            && (DateTime.Now - n.ReadyDateTime.Value).Days > 30));
```

Comment: query comprehension... as non-native English that sounds like abracadabra :)

Answer (score 1):

Or to avoid the need for '!', just reverse the query:

```
act = from n in act
where (!n.Ready || n.ReadyDateTime ==null || (DateTime.Now - n.ReadyDateTime.Value).Days <= 30)
select n;
```

Comment: just even simplier `n.Ready == false` is equal to `!n.Ready`

Comment: @Alex: Very true.  Quirky personal preference I kinda stopped using 'not' operator long ago, less explicit and too easily overlooked.